Lower OptaPy verbosity
I'm using OptaPy's planner to solve an optimization problem. All is well but since I must solve a high number of problems sequentially I would like for the OptaPy's solver to stop printing status messages on the standard output.
I can't seem to find any help in their documentation but I'm sure there must be a way to do this.
This is the solver's initialization:
problem = generate_problem(<arguments>)

solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig()
solver_config \
        .withSolutionClass(SolutionObj) \
        .withEntityClasses(EntityCLass) \
        .withConstraintProviderClass(study_plan_constraints) \
        .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(30))

solution = solver_factory_create(solver_config)\
        .buildSolver()\
        .solve(problem)

The status printed on the terminal (that I wish to get rid of) is this:
13:53:44.474 [main        ] INFO  Solving started: time spent (127), best score (-1160hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0).
13:53:44.480 [main        ] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (133), best score (-1160hard/0soft), score calculation speed (1000/sec), step total (0).
13:53:54.347 [main        ] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (10000), best score (0hard/-6soft), score calculation speed (179/sec), step total (1540).
13:53:54.348 [main        ] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (10000), best score (0hard/-6soft), score calculation speed (177/sec), phase total (2), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE).

I'm confident there exists a function for setting the solver's verbosity but I can't find it.
